# Redirect URL in browser before Proxy Pass

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am trying to remove the trailing slash from all of my URLs and redirect.

I've accomplished this here:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/ >
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ ${BaseUrl}/$1 [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

However, I am also running a service locally and want to proxy to it visits /${ServiceRoot}.

```
ProxyPass /${ServiceRoot} http://localhost:${ServicePort}/
ProxyPassReverse /${ServiceRoot} http://localhost:${ServicePort}/
```

Each of these works fine individually. However, if I try to visit a URL like this: `${BaseUrl}/${ServiceRoot}/some/path/`

The trailing slash is left on. I would like to force a redirect so the URL in the browser shows without the trailing slash.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the L from the RewriteRule:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ ${BaseUrl}/$1 [R=301]
```

That should apply the rule to your ProxyPass directive. Just remember to check [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) if you plan to support directory listings, it will try to redirect directories to / and then back in a loop.

Comment: I tried this. It still doesn't work for paths that cause the proxy to be contacted.

Comment: This is what I have: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8227405/ I'm proxying /upc to another host, the rewrite stays in place. Note that directory listings stopped working on both the local addresses and the under /upc as well (as was expected).

Comment: In your example, your rewrite is outside of the <Directory> tag. When I have the Rewrite rules outside of the <Directory> section, I don't get any rewrite behavior.

Comment: Also, just to verify. With what you have here, if you visit `/upc/some/sub/dir/` it redirects to `http://upc-v2/some/sub/dir`? Specifically missing the trailing slash.

Comment: Yeah, if I go to any address ending with / it gets redirected, something like `upc/referencias/` ends being -> `/upc/referencias` in the browser's address bar. But that breaks any directory listings (if enabled) like `/upc/img/ -> /upc/img -> /upc/img/` (loop)

Answer (score 0):

You probably got something like this in your apache config:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
</Proxy>
```

Then you have to add the following in order to proxy-pass all requests to www.olddomain.com/foo to www.newdomain.com/bar

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule /foo(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/bar/$1 [P,L]
```

What this does is:

When a request is made to host www.olddomain.com the RewriteRule will fire
This rule substitutes /foo to http://www.newdomain.com/bar/
The substitution is handed over to mod_proxy (P)
Stop rewriting (L)
Example result:

Browser is configured to use your apache as proxy server
It requests www.olddomain.com/foo/test.html
Your apache will rewrite this to www.newdomain.com/bar/test.html
It will request this page from the responsible webserver
Return the result to the browser as www.olddomain.com/foo/test.html